# android filename from uri is not the same as actual filename

Tags: android, file, uri

I need to get the name and extension of a file that I need to upload. I let the user select the file using an Intent call and get the URI as follows:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
/* stuff */
Uri uri = data.getData();
String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
Log.d("filePath ",filePath);
Log.d("URI ", uri.toString());
String fileName = (new File(filePath)).getName();
Log.d("fileName ",fileName);
```

but the results are as follows:

> com.blah.blah D/URI: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/354
>   com.blah.blah D/filePath: /document/354
>   com.blah.blah D/fileName: 354

the name of the file isn't even 354! its a PDF file (say "Bus e-Ticket.pdf" or "Xender.apk")

`String fileName = (new File(filePath)).getAbsolutePath();`
also yields the same. 
how can i get the file name/exstension on disk?

Comment: then use `ContentResolver` API

Answer (score 2):

> but the results are as follows

`getPath()` is pointless on a `Uri` with a `content` scheme. `getPath()` is pointless on a `Uri` with any scheme other than `file`.

> the name of the file isn't even 354

There is no requirement that there be a file. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060367/android-filename-from-uri-is-not-the-same-as-actual-filename` is a `Uri`, and I feel fairly confident that there is no file on a Stack Overflow server at the path `/questions/46060367/android-filename-from-uri-is-not-the-same-as-actual-filename`.

> how can i get the file name/exstension on disk?

There is no requirement that the user choose something that is a file. You can use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` and `getName()` to get a "display name" for the content identified by the `Uri`. That does not have to be a filename with an extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MediaStore class to obtain the filename seen by the user. In specific use the [MediaColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns) interface as shown below

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};
        ContentResolver cr = mctx.getContentResolver();
        Cursor metaCursor = cr.query(uri[0], projection, null, null, null);
        if (metaCursor != null) {
            try {
                if (metaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    realFileName = metaCursor.getString(0);
                }
            } finally {
                metaCursor.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note that not every `Uri` will support `MediaColumns`.